# SpringBoot Embedded Tomcat and GoogleCloud

Tags: spring-boot, maven, google-cloud-platform

When i add the Google Cloud repository and some Google dependecies to my SpringBoot / WebMVC / JSP application:

```
**<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
            <version>24.0.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>**

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    **<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-texttospeech</artifactId>
    </dependency>**

</dependencies>
```

Maven fails to execute goal spring-boot:run due to :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-alts\1.41.0\grpc-auth-1.41.0.jar (File not found)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:241) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:383) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs(StandardJarScanner.java:318) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.doScanClassPath(StandardJarScanner.java:270) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:233) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262) [tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
```

Is there a compatibilty problem with these repositories ? Without using the Google dependencies everything is fine.

Comment: try to add [this BOM](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp#spring-cloud-gcp-bill-of-materials-bom) to your pom.xml <dependencyManagement> section. This will allow you to not specify versions for any of the Maven dependencies and instead delegate versioning to the BOM.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i have a similar error, the only trick i found is to manually copy lots of jar in one of my dependency folder grpc-netty-shaded\1.41.0